# Facebook API, no email field in /me

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using javascript + PHP

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'>
  <body>
        <fb:login-button scope='email,user_photos'></fb:login-button>
        <div id='fb-root' ></div>
                <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '478449982166112',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>.
      </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am requesting email permissions .

Then I call /me from PHP:

```
 $user = $facebook->getUser();

 if ($user) {
    try {
        // if user is logged on to facebook, the account details will be saved in $me variable
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        // if user is not logged on to facebook, set $user to null . 
        $user = null;
    }
 }
```

but it doesn't contain the email field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not requesting `email` permission in PHP, only in Javascript. Javascript runs in your browser, PHP runs on the server.

To generate a login URL and redirect to it in PHP, try this:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if (!$user) {
    header('Location: ' . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email')));
    exit;
} else {
    try {
        // if user is logged on to facebook, the account details will be saved in $me variable
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        // if user is not logged on to facebook, set $user to null . 
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I still use the javascript popup to login in this case?

Comment: @FAndrei You might be able to login via JS, get the token with [`FB.getAuthResponse`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/), send it to your backend/PHP code and then use [`$facebook->setAccessToken('token from JS')`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L341). Someone correct me if this is wrong

Comment: _“Where”_ from you request a permission does not matter – once the user granted it to your app, it’s granted (until they maybe revoke it again). And you don’t have to push access tokens around, if you have set `cookie: true` when embedding the JS SDK – then, on the _next(!)_ request, PHP will automatically be able to use the access token received by client-side login.